# Why was this question on searching for a string across an entire overleaf project closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/148713/18147):

> I have a project in Overleaf containing several latex files. How can I search for a string across all files of a project in Overleaf?

was closed by 1 mod. The comment left by the mod was:

> We're looking for longer posts that provide some explanation and context. Don't just ask a one-line question; provide some background like a brief description of your research prior to asking. Ref. How to Ask.

The comment doesn't clearly state the reason for the close vote. Is it because of no research shown? Is it because something is unclear? Is it because I have to add more context for the reader to understand the question? Etc.

And the [questions timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/148713/timeline) gives the following information for the closure:

> Needs details or clarity

As a result, I still don't understand why the question could close because:

1. The question is crystal clear as far as I can see, and the mod didn't point to which part I should clarify.
2. Lack of brief description of your research prior isn't a reason to close a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still have no idea why the question got closed by 1 mod, I reposted the question into a longer post that provides some "explanation and context"  (which doesn't help at all explaining the question, but whatever). [How can I search for a string across all files of a project in Overleaf?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/149283/18147)